# XAML for floating window in AvalonDock

Tags: xaml, floating, avalondock

Can someone provide me with an AvalonDock XAML code piece that when run opens the app with a floating window instead of being always docked inside the dock pane? I've seen programmatic ways to do it, but I thought there must be a way to specify it in XAML. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is a bit late, but hopefully it will help someone with the same issue in the future...

To create a floating document, add a *LayoutDocumentFloatingWindow* as a child of *LayoutDocumentFloatingWindow*, and then add your *LayoutDocument* as a child of the *LayoutDocumentFloatingWindow*, as below:

```
<xcad:DockingManager>
    <xcad:LayoutRoot>
        <xcad:LayoutRoot.FloatingWindows>
            <xcad:LayoutDocumentFloatingWindow>
                <xcad:LayoutDocument Title="My Document">
                    <!--Add document content here-->
                </xcad:LayoutDocument>
            </xcad:LayoutDocumentFloatingWindow>
       </xcad:LayoutRoot.FloatingWindows>
    </xcad:LayoutRoot>
  </xcad:DockingManager>
```

Similarly you can add anchorables like so:

```
<xcad:DockingManager>
<xcad:LayoutRoot>
    <xcad:LayoutRoot.FloatingWindows>
        <xcad:LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindow>
            <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
              <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                 <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="My anchorable">
                    <!--Add anchorable content here-->
                 </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
              </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
           </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
       </xcad:LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindow>
   </xcad:LayoutRoot.FloatingWindows>
</xcad:LayoutRoot>
```

Note that unlike LayoutDocuments, for anchorables you need to add a group pane rather than just a single LayoutAnchorable, because floating anchorables are designed to be able to be grouped in a single window but LayoutDocuments are not.

As a more general guide, an example of how to set up varioius layout elements in a DockingManager can be found here: https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/AvalonDock.html

Comment: Thanks, this does work! I will also mention that once layout serialization is implemented, then a declarative layout as in my question becomes less important as the layout can be saved in whatever state one needs, and that state can be made a default state when the user doesn't provide his own layout file.